# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set

Tags: java, maven, javafx, fxml

I am getting the following error. I have attached my code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
at com.John.Smith.Cars.Main.start(Main.java:31)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
... 1 more
```

Here is my Main class.

```
package com.John.Smith.Cars;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));

        //PushNPull p = new PushNPull();
        //p.populateSQL();

        StageWithData window = new StageWithData(primaryStage);
        FXMLLoader hpLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/homePage.fxml"));



        System.out.println(hpLoader.getController() + ", " + hpLoader.getLocation());
        Parent root = hpLoader.load(); //This is the line with the error
        ControllerHomePage controller = hpLoader.getController();
        controller.setStage(window);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles.css").toExternalForm());
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

        new Thread(() -> {
                abstractSensorDriver sDriver = new SensorDriverTest(window);
                sDriver.startCollection();
        }).start();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I have seen the other posts with the same error, but still does not seem to work.
[JAVAFX: Location is not set error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755630/javafx-location-is-not-set-error?rq=1)
["java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set" in JavaFX application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315121/java-lang-illegalstateexception-location-is-not-set-in-javafx-application)

EDIT: Here are the first few lines of my homePage.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" stylesheets="@styles.css" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.John.Smith.Cars.ControllerHomePage">
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
    </rowConstraints>
```

I have my FXML files in the same folder as my Main class.
I am using Maven for this project (my first maven project).

After running the Main method. My println() for the loader location prints out "Null , Null"

Comment: please attach your `homePage.fxml` file

Comment: I just attached my homePage.fxml.

Comment: Should be `getResource("/com/John/Smith/Cars/homePage.fxml")`. If this does not work you need to check, if the fxml is in the classpath at runtime...

Comment: When you say, "_I have my FXML files in the same folder as my Main class_", does that mean the FXML files are in the `src\main\java` directory? If so, I believe this is your issue. Maven does not copy resources from the `src\main\java` directory into the output directory (at least by default). Instead, move your FXML files into the `src\main\resources` directory. That is where resources (i.e. non-`.java` files) belong. [Maven - Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: @Slaw. That was it. I did not have my FXML files in a resource folder. I had it in my src\main\java directory. After I created a resource folder and added it to my POM file, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the file is in the same folder as the class calling the loader, you should not have a `/` in the file path.

Change the line to:

`FXMLLoader hpLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("homePage.fxml"));`

You are trying to set the loader to look for that file in the root project folder.

Comment: I had it working before I used Maven. I moved all of my files to a new Maven project and it is giving me the error now. I am wondering if it has something to do with my folder structure or perhaps my POM file??